# Input sequential identifier for each group of names in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for any suggestions as to how I can to look through a column that is sorted by name and input a sequential number to the left for each group(i.e. first block of names = 1, 2nd block of names  = 2 and so on)  Please see example below:

```
    1   ALAMEDA
1   ALAMEDA
1   ALAMEDA
1   ALAMEDA
1   ALAMEDA
1   ALAMEDA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
2   CONTRA COSTA
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
3   LOS ANGELES
```

This is only a sample of a much larger list.  I have an existing code that I have been able to modify from this forum that will identify each group of names in the column as a series and paste all the data on a new worksheet per name.  I'm blocked on the possibilities of where to modify it to do this excercise.
The data starts at row 2, the identifier I want to input is in column B and the names are in column C.  Shown below is that macro as a base but the question is open to any suggestions.

```
Sub AllocatedataCSVwkb()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("CSV Master")
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' stop processing if we don't have any data
    If lastRow < 2 Then Exit Sub

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    CopyDataToSheets lastRow, ws
    ws.Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Sub CopyDataToSheets(lastRow As Long, src As Worksheet)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Series As String
    Dim SeriesStart As Long
    Dim SeriesLast As Long

    Set rng = Range("C1:C" & lastRow)
    SeriesStart = 1
    Series = Range("C" & SeriesStart)
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.Value <> Series Then
            SeriesLast = cell.Row - 1
            CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series
            Series = cell.Value
            SeriesStart = cell.Row
        End If
    Next
    ' copy the last series
    SeriesLast = lastRow
    CopySeriesToNewSheet src, SeriesStart, SeriesLast, Series

End Sub

Sub CopySeriesToNewSheet(src As Worksheet, Start As Long, Last As Long, _
                                                        name As String)
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Dim tgt As Worksheet

    Set tgt = wb.Sheets(1)
    tgt.name = name


    ' copy data from src to tgt
    src.Range("A" & Start & ":O" & Last).Copy
    tgt.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    wb.SaveAs name.xls, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close (True)

End Sub

Function SheetExists(name As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    SheetExists = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets(name)
    If ws Is Nothing Then
       SheetExists = False
    End If
End Function
```

Please note that I do not want to allocate it to a different spreadsheet.  The macro is only an example of what I think can be modified for the situation I'm encountering.

Comment: in `B2` wirte `=1`, in `B3` write `=IF(C2=C3,B2,B2+1)` and drag it down